# How to block Google Images while allowing Google?

Tags: google-search

It's harder and harder to block Google Images while allowing Google as their respective URLs have become very similar.

Still, is there any way to achieve it today ?

Comment: your browser and your OS might help here, might help as well if you tell why you intend to do so.

Comment: i'm wondering what "Google Images" means. Do you want to stop yourself from performing a Google Image Search? One would think you could do that just by not using Google's image search.

Comment: Your intentions matter, so we really kinda need to know what you're after. There's always a way to achieve it, but the best way completely depends on the situation.

Comment: OK sorry for that, the reason I want to block Google Images is to prevent my son from seeing certain things that the Google Safe Search option blocks only partially.

Comment: @drake035 : what kind of images are you talking about?